# Label handling in a macro

Tags: macros, subcaption

I want to create an environment to easily list a bunch of subfigures with their explanations. But the explanations should appear only in the caption of the complete figure, instead of the subfigure's caption.

In order to solve this problem, I devised an environment that uses a command to append to a macro the subfigure captions. However, when I try to refer to the labels (that are created on the fly) for the subfigures in the resulting caption, they all refer to the last subfigure. I used `\expandafter` to append to my collecting macro, so I suspect this might be the problem.

---

The corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%
% ===================== %
% smallSubfigExplained  %
% ===================== %
\newlength\sseWidth
\def\sseExplanationOutput{}
\newcounter{sseTotalCounter}
\newcounter{sseCounter}[sseTotalCounter]

\newenvironment{smallSubfigExplained}{%
    \stepcounter{sseTotalCounter}
    \def\sseExplanationOutput{}
}{%
    \caption[cap]{\sseExplanationOutput}
}
\newcommand\sseItem[1]{%    
    \stepcounter{sseCounter}
    \def\lblname{sse:\thesseTotalCounter-\thesseCounter}
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\sseExplanationOutput\expandafter{%
        \sseExplanationOutput
        \textbf{\subref{\lblname}})
        #1
    }
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
            \rule{2cm}{2cm}
            \caption{}
            \label{\lblname}
    \end{subfigure}     
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{smallSubfigExplained}
            \sseItem{subfig expl 1}
            \sseItem{second subfig expl}
        \end{smallSubfigExplained}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I would say it is obvious if all subfigures have the same label - you should receive a warning like `multiple definition`. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `\def` on `\sseExplanationOutput` was self-referential, which doesn't work with `\def`.  Normally, you would use an `\edef`, but in this case, the `\subref{}` doesn't work in an `\edef`, so you need a `\protected@edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%
% ===================== %
% smallSubfigExplained  %
% ===================== %
\newlength\sseWidth
\def\sseExplanationOutput{}
\newcounter{sseTotalCounter}
\newcounter{sseCounter}[sseTotalCounter]

\newenvironment{smallSubfigExplained}{%
    \stepcounter{sseTotalCounter}
    \def\sseExplanationOutput{}
}{%
    \caption[cap]{\sseExplanationOutput}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sseItem[1]{%    
    \stepcounter{sseCounter}
    \def\lblname{sse:\thesseTotalCounter-\thesseCounter}
    \protected@edef\sseExplanationOutput{%
        \sseExplanationOutput
        \textbf{\subref{\lblname}})
        #1
    }
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
            \rule{2cm}{2cm}
            \caption{}
            \label{\lblname}
    \end{subfigure}     
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{smallSubfigExplained}
            \sseItem{subfig expl 1}
            \sseItem{second subfig expl}
        \end{smallSubfigExplained}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]